# How to read input in Python3 and remove the spaces between?

Tags: python-3.x

On websites like hackerrank, which I have just recently been introduced to, there are some problems where the input is:

```
1 5 9
```

And they want these to be different variables.
Is there a way to read this input with

```
input()
```

But then make the three parts of the input different variables?
I have tried:

```
list_input = input().split(' ')
```

But this only creates a list of strings.
Is there a better way to create different variables from only one line of input?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you want multiple variables for this?

Comment: Please take the effort to google your queries before posting them here

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this:

```
>>> variables = input ("Enter an input separated by space: ")
Enter an input separated by space: 1 5 9
>>> variables
'1 5 9'
>>> 
>>> variables = variables.split (' ')
>>> variables
['1', '5', '9']
>>> variables [1]
'5'
>>> 
>>> for var in variables:
print (var)
1
5
9
>>>
```